# Как сделать затухающую строку на JQuery (или CSS)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Нужно сделать небольшое затухание, как на картинке[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно плагин есть какой?
Облазил гугл в поисках решения, возможно не так ставлю вопрос, надежда на вас)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно на ссылку "Все отзывы" добавить стили на псевдоэлемент :before

```
a.allreviews {
    position: relative;
}
a.allreviews:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.01) 1%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 73%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.01) 1%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 73%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.01) 1%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 73%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```